# File doesn't attach on create but attaches on update for zendesk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zendesk, zendesk-api

The workflow should be users should be able to attach files to comments on zendesk ticket regardless if it's a new ticket or existing ticket.

Currently attaching files to comments on existing tickets works perfectly fine. However, if you look at the create action is where it does nothing as far as being able to attach the file. It doesn't throw an error but just doesn't attach the file. I'm sure it's the way my code is flowing but can't figure it out.

```
require_dependency 'zen_support/application_controller'

module ZenSupport
  class TicketsController < ApplicationController
    include SmartListing::Helper::ControllerExtensions
    helper  SmartListing::Helper

    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :zen_update
    before_action :set_new_ticket, only: [:new, :create]
    before_action :get_ticket, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :zen_update]
    before_action :authorize_ticket, except: :zen_update

    rescue_from ZendeskAPI::Error::NetworkError, with: :network_error

    def new
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end

    def index
      if zen_list_type == 'datatable'
        @tickets = tickets
      else
        smart_listing
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    end

    def create
      if(!@ticket.valid? && (@ticket.errors.keys - [:zendesk_id]).present?)
        # test if ticket is invalid beyond just missing zendesk_id
        raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new @ticket
      else
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          @zendesk_ticket.save!
          upload_to_zendesk(params[:comment], params[:attachments])
          @ticket.zendesk_id = @zendesk_ticket.id
          @ticket.status = @zendesk_ticket.status
          @ticket.save!
          smart_listing

          flash.now[:success] = "Your help request was successfully submitted.\n
          Your support ticket number is ##{@zendesk_ticket.id}.\n\n
          You should receive a confirmation email shortly.\n\n
          Thank you!"
        end
      end
    rescue Exception => exception
      flash.now[:error] = exception.to_s
      @zendesk_ticket.delete if @zendesk_ticket.id
      render :new
    end

    def show
      render action: :edit
    end

    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js do
          # don't save over comment, just use the field for validation
          upload_to_zendesk(params[:comment], params[:attachments])
          @zendesk_ticket.update(ticket_update_params)
          if @ticket.valid? && @zendesk_ticket.save! && @ticket.update(updated_at: Time.now)
            flash.now[:success] = "Your help request was successfully updated.\n
            Your support ticket number is ##{@zendesk_ticket.id}.\n\n
            You should receive a confirmation email shortly.\n\n
            Thank you!"
          else
            flash.now[:error] = if @ticket.errors.present?
              @ticket.errors.full_messages.join "\n"
            else
              'There was a problem sending out your request.'
            end
            render action: :edit
          end
        end
      end
    end

    def zen_update
      ZenSupport::Ticket.find_by(
        zendesk_id: params[:id]
      )&.update(zen_update_params)

      render nothing: true
    end

    def network_error
      flash.now[:error] = 'There was a network error connecting to the Zendesk API. Try again later.'
      render 'network_error'
    end

    private

    def upload_to_zendesk(comment_body, files)
      @zendesk_ticket.comment = { value: comment_body }
      Array(files).each do |file|
        @zendesk_ticket.comment.uploads << file
      end
    end

    def tickets
      ZenSupport::Ticket.where user: current_user
    end

    def smart_listing
      smart_listing_create(
        :support_tickets,
        tickets,
        partial: 'zen_support/tickets/list',
        array: tickets.count != 0
        # we want to use array: true if there are records present because it pre-renders the activerecord
        # objects so we can do sorting on the encrypted field 'subject'. BUT, if there are no records, 
        # then array: true gives us a pagination error
      )
    end

    def ticket_params
      {
        subject: subject,
        comment: comment,
        zendesk_id: zendesk_id,
        zendesk_submitter_id: submitter_id,
        ticket_type: ticket_type,
        priority: priority,
        tags: tags,
        user: current_user
      }
    end

    def zendesk_ticket_params
      {
        subject: subject,
        type: ticket_type,
        comment: { value: comment },
        submitter_id: submitter_id,
        requester_id: requester_id,
        priority: priority,
        tags: tags
      }
    end

    def ticket_update_params
      {
        comment: {
          body: params[:comment],
          author_id: zendesk_user.id
        }
      }
    end

    def zen_update_params
      {
        zendesk_id: zendesk_id,
        status: @zendesk_ticket.status,
        priority: @zendesk_ticket.priority,
        updated_at: @zendesk_ticket.updated_at
      }
    end

    def subject
      params.dig :zen_support_ticket, :subject
    end

    def comment
      params.dig :zen_support_ticket, :comment
    end

    def zendesk_id
      @zendesk_ticket.id
    end

    def tags
      [
        *params.dig(:zen_support_ticket, :tags),
        *ZenSupport.configuration.options[:support_ticket_attributes][:static_tags]
      ]
    end

    def ticket_type
      params.dig(:zen_support_ticket, :ticket_type).to_s.downcase
    end

    def set_new_ticket
      @zendesk_ticket = ZendeskAPI::Ticket.new(
        zen_client, zendesk_ticket_params
      )
      @ticket = ZenSupport::Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    end

    def get_ticket
      @zendesk_ticket = ZendeskAPI::Ticket.find!(
        zen_client,
        id: params[:id]
      )
      @ticket = ZenSupport::Ticket.find_by!(zendesk_id: params[:id])
    end

    def priority
      (params.dig(:zen_support_ticket, :priority) || ZenSupport.configuration.options[:support_ticket_attributes][:default_priority]).downcase
    end

    def submitter_id
      zendesk_user.id
    end

    def requester_id
      zendesk_user.id
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:zen_support_user).permit(tags: [])
    end

    def zendesk_user
      @zendesk_user ||= (get_zendesk_user || create_zendesk_user)
    end

    def get_zendesk_user
      zen_client.users.search(
        query: "email:#{zen_current_user.email}"
      ).first
    end

    def create_zendesk_user
      ZendeskAPI::User.create(
        zen_client,
        email: zen_current_user.email,
        name: zen_current_user.full_name,
        tags: user_tags
      )
    end

    def user_tags
      ZenSupport.configuration.user_setup[:static_tags]
    end

     def authorize_ticket
      authorize Ticket
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this one-line to your create-method

```
def create
  if(!@ticket.valid? && (@ticket.errors.keys - [:zendesk_id]).present?)
    # test if ticket is invalid beyond just missing zendesk_id
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new @ticket
  else
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @zendesk_ticket.save!
      upload_to_zendesk(params[:comment], params[:attachments])
      @zendesk_ticket.save!
      ...
```

Comment: ehhh is there not another way? I feel this way may not be the best practice

Comment: if you like the best practice, there will be a lot of changes to your code. You can start with Autosave Association (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html).  Your model structure is not shown, so I cannot provide other information.

Comment: Right. Unfortunately that doesn't work making the change to the create action